# Zip file downloading as HTML

Tags: java, google-chrome, download, zip, microsoft-edge

I am using a Java web application to create a zip file using the response output stream, and setting the response headers.

When Chrome/Edge come to download the file, they treat it as an html file rather than a zip.

renaming the .html that is downloaded to .zip then gives the correct file, so I'm creating the zip correctly.

If I set Edge to prompt for download, rather than automatically download files, I can then treat it as a zip on download.

IE11 correctly downloads as a zip.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(servletOutputStream));
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis= new BufferedInputStream(fis);

// Write the contents of the file
int data = 0;
while ((data = bis.read()) != -1) 
{
   zos.write(data);
}
bis.close();
fis.close();
zos.flush();
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
servletOutputStream.close();

response.setContentType("Content-type: text/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName.zip");
```

Comment: Try setting the headers first

Comment: You could try to set the `Content-Type` response header to the value `application/zip` (or `application/octet-stream`, depending on the target browser).

Comment: Thanks @g00se that works. Xudong Peng, that doesn't seem to make any difference, at least not without also doing g00se's thing. G00se if you want to write up the answer I'll tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the headers first before you do anything else